# How to disable the controlls of youtube Player View in android?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have made a youtube api demo,And myl requirement is i want to disable the userControlls from YoutubePlayerView(seekbar),I have searched and find a solution about it,But i dont know how to  apply it in my code.Can any one suggest me howw to disable the seekbar from youtube Player View in android?

My code is as below:

**code**

```
public class VideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        OnClickListener, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    Button btn_toprated;
    TextView tv_site;
    TextView tv_guide;
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBV-3VbYw-ljgkj9tDg5pOVEAE8hNmG6q8";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "1QydBspryNE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_activity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
        PlayerStyle style = PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS;

    }

    void init() {

        btn_toprated = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_toprated);
        tv_guide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_guide);
        tv_site = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_site);
        btn_toprated.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_guide.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_site.setOnClickListener(this);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);

        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.tv_guide:
            i = new Intent(VideoActivity.this, GuideActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_site:
            String url = "http://www.system500.com";
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_toprated:
            i = new Intent(VideoActivity.this, TopRatedActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle) enum class, either in this way

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
```

or

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
```

Comment: Can I disable youtube player seek bar?

Answer (score 1):

**Enum values**

> **public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle CHROMELESS**
>
> A style that shows no interactive player controls.

> **public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle DEFAULT**
>
> The default style, showing all interactive controls.

> **public static final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle MINIMAL**
>
> A minimal style, showing only a time bar and play/pause controls.

Try the following:

```
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onInitializationSuccess!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    if (youTubePlayer == null) 
        return;
    
    // Start buffering
    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
}
```